# wrong JSON data passes from PHP to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having trouble with reading data from `json_encode`.
when I set action to current page and isolate the two part of code for sending `json` data It works well, but after I change the action destination to another page for example `procees.php` and put echo `json_encode` at the end of the code It returns hole of `Html` code in data variable and the `js` alert '2' and seems that `json` data get wrong value
can somebody tell me where I go wrong?

index.php code :

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="submit.js" ></script>
<body>

    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input  name  = "name"    type = "text"  />
    <input  name  = "family"  type = "text"  />
    <input  name  = "year"    type = "number" maxlength="4" min="1300" max="1393"/>
    <input  name  = "month"   type = "number" maxlength="2" min="1" max="12"/>
    <input  name  = "day"     type = "number" maxlength="2" min="1" max="31"/>
    <input  value ="submit"   type = "submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and process.php code

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
    include("classes.php");

        /* declare all objects */
        /* Initialization */
        $name    =  trim( $_POST["name"] );
        /*and Initial all the variables*/

                if (!($check->alphabetSyntaxChecking($name))) {
         $errors['name'] = "please check your inserts";
        }
          /*validate another inputs ... */


            if ( ! empty($errors)) {
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['errors']  = $errors;
              } else {
            $data['success'] = true;
            $poem = $fileContent->readFromFile("poem.txt", $remain, $moshakhasat);
                $allPoem = $poem[1];
                $data['allpoem'] = $allPoem;    
        }
            echo json_encode($data);
```

and Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
$.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'process.php', 
            data        : $(this).serialize(),
            dataType    : 'json',
            encode      : true

        })
    .done(function(data) {
    alert("1");
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
           alert("2");
            });
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: when you got all html in alert,it means something is wrong in your php file. try confirm by alerting values which are actually received by php

Comment: I see the values of data that received by PHP by firebug , data is initial with HTMl code

Comment: try to output error that you get on ajax fail `.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {alert("status: "+status+", error: "+error);});`, also you may check the response body in firebug for possible php errors

Comment: @paulitto status:parserror syntax error :json parse error: unrecognized token '<'   this error return and I know it means the data has HTML syntax but I expect jsone_encode return an array

Comment: can you show what is the actual response from process.php? You may see this in network tab in firebug or chrome dev tools

Comment: @paulitto returns :<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 
 

</body>
</html>{"success":true,"allpoem":["\u062f\u0648\u0634 \u0633\u0648\u062f\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u062e\u0634 \u06af\u0641\u062a\u0645 \u0632 \u0633\u0631 \u0628\u064a\u0631\u0648\u0646 \u06a9\u0646\u0645\r"   and more

Comment: obviously not a valid json :) Looks like your process.php outputs something before json_encode

Comment: @paulitto yes I know that but I want to understand which part of code destroy the json data and change it to html , there isn't any code after echo json_encode to append or change but ... :(

Comment: your json is not destroyed, it goes right after </html>, its just that you output html additionally before it ( before echo json_encode), have a look at your classes.php and check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove json_encode($data) to be sure what is return from process.php file,if anything else is 
        in data that may be from classes.php file , that's why u get html tags on response

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : 'process.php', 
                data        : $(this).serialize(),
                dataType    : 'json',
                encode      : true

            })
        .success(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
        })
        .error function(jqxhr)
                {
                 //it  will be errors: 324, 500, 404 or anythings else
                 console.log(jqxhr.responseText); 
                }
    event.preventDefault();
    });
    });
```

Comment: when I use var_dump function instead of json_encode to see what is fill  data variable  it exactly is what i want. in classes.php is just some classes that i declare for validation and they work true

Comment: Did you set any cookie??

Comment: No I dont set any cookie or session